# antd autocomplete dropdown styling

Tags: reactjs, antd

Hi is there any way to style antd autocomplete drop down?
Like i want a grid inside the drop down i used dropdownrender but it is not working

```
<AutoComplete
        style={{
          width: 200,
        }}
        ref={input}
        allowClear={true}
        dropdownStyle={{ minWidth: "400px" }}
        notFoundContent={
          result.length >= 1 ? "<p>Search For Product</p>" : "No Product"
        }
        dropdownRender={(menu) => console.log("menu", menu)}
        onSearch={handleSearch}
        placeholder="Search Product here"
        options={result.map((e) => ({ label: e.name, value: e.name }))}
        onSelect={handleSelect}
        // onChange={onChange}
        onChange={(value) => debounceSearch(value)}
      />
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: @lissettdm no error, i just want to render dropdown using my own style.

Comment: Is  this line executed: console.log("menu", menu)??

Comment: yes it is returning symbol something object

Comment: You can also provide `label` in options as react node.. have you tried it? @RishavSinha

Comment: @TusharTambe can you please elaborate more.

Comment: ```options = [
    {
      "label" : <Button type="primary">Apple</Button>,
      "value" : "Apple"
    },
    {
      "label" :  <Text type="secondary">Banana</Text>,
      "value" : "Banana"
    },
    {
      "label" :  <Text type="success">Grapes</Text>,
      "value" : "Grapes"
    }]```

you can have your options like this... by this you can control the styling of items shown.. not sure this helps your concern of styling dropdown.